# Deduce member function return type using a class member function object

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

**Edit**: I feel kind of silly now. The posted code actually works with ???=`decltype(acc(base(i)))`... The error was something else - highly confusing though. I will post [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136632/order-of-declaration-matters-when-using-decltype-for-member-function-return-type) about that. Thank you for your help.

---

I have some code like this:

```
template<typename Base, typename Acc>
struct Foo
{
    Base base;
    Acc acc;

    auto operator()(unsigned i) const -> decltype(???) // what is ???
    { return acc(base(i)); }
};
```

How do I get the correct return type?

I tried with `decltype(acc(base(i)))` but this gives an error (using GCC 4.6.3):

> there are no arguments to ‘base’ that depend on a template parameter,
>   so a declaration of ‘base’ must be available

Comment: As a work-around, try `decltype(acc(this->base(i)))` or even `decltype(this->acc(this->base(i)))`.

Comment: Try more recent GCC. I tried that with GCC 4.8.1 in Ubuntu - it worked

Comment: I believe `decltype(acc(base(i)))` is correct (unless the problem is in some code that you haven't shown) but gcc 4.6.3 is too old to have implemented it correctly (it works on gcc 4.8.1). Try to update your compiler or the workaround given by Daniel Frey.

Comment: You could try to 'fully qualify' the ??? with Foo<Base,Acc>::... and see if it appreciates a from-the-ground-up approach

Comment: @DanielFrey While this workaround is ok for gcc, most times it is problematic with clang. I have always been troubled with this and I usually find some entirely different solution without any `decltype`.

Comment: @iavr Upgrading seems to most sensible option when possible, but if you are stuck on some specific compiler/version, you have to deal with it. I offered the GCC-work-around since OP was stating that he uses GCC 4.6.3.

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev In my own real code (not toy examples) the problem persists definitely in GCC 4.8.1, I think 4.8.2 as well. I have never managed (or even tried) to reproduce it in small self-contained example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been troubled for hours or days around such problems. Typically gcc wants `this->` but clang does not. In some cases `Foo::` also helps but there have been cases where I have given up using the member names. The following is only using the *type* names and (though more verbose) I think will not have any problems with either:

```
template<typename Base, typename Acc>
struct Foo
{
    Base base;
    Acc acc;

    template<typename S>
    using result = typename std::result_of<S>::type;

    auto operator()(unsigned i) const
    -> result<const Acc(result<const Base(unsigned)>)>
        { return acc(base(i)); }
};
```

More generally, whenever `decltype(member_name)` is causing problems, you can safely use `decltype(std::declval<member_type>())` where `member_type` is `const`-qualified if the member function using it is `const`.

Even more generally, if you have a member function that is `&&`, `&` or `const&` qualified, use `member_type`, `member_type&` or `const member_type&` respectively in such expressions.

I have never looked into what the standard says but in practice compilers treat expressions differently in trailing return types and inside function definitions when it comes to class members.

Comment: Careful with `const`: The `operator()(unsigned i)` is `const`, hence are `base` and `acc`. I think you'd need `result<const Acc(result<const Base(unsigned)>)>`. +1 anyways :)

Comment: @DanielFrey Thanks, corrected. In fact, whenever I have a generic function object that holds data I end up with 3 overloads of `operator()` (`&&`, `&` and `const&`) and all types adjusted as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check tomorrow at work.