# Order of declaration matters when using decltype for member function return type

Tags: c++11, decltype

Why does this work:

```
template<typename Base, typename Acc>
struct Foo
{
    Base base;
    Acc acc;

    auto operator()(unsigned i) const -> decltype(acc(base(i)))
    { return acc(base(i)); }
};
```

and this gives a compiler error:

```
template<typename Base, typename Acc>
struct Foo
{
    auto operator()(unsigned i) const -> decltype(acc(base(i)))
    { return acc(base(i)); }

    Base base;
    Acc acc;    
};
```

> error: there are no arguments to ‘base’ that depend on a template
>   parameter, so a declaration of ‘base’ must be available [-fpermissive]

Is that really intended by the standard or a bug with GCC 4.8.1?

---

I found an even shorter example for demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int x;

    auto getx() const -> decltype(x) // OK
    { return x; }

    auto gety() const -> decltype(y) // ERROR
    { return y; }

    int gety2() const // OK
    { return y; }

    int y;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo f {1,2};
    std::cout << f.getx() << std::endl;
    std::cout << f.gety() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this can show](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fc81e3ec3aa910c) why it's necessary *not* to postpone name lookup inside the trailing-return-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected to have only members declared prior to the function declaration. As seen in §5.1.1 bullet 3 of the standard :

> If a declaration declares a member function … [ Note: **only class members declared prior
>   to the declaration are visible**. —end note ]

Comment: i am looking in the standard if i find something as i was catch by it. Offtopic, in c++1y, you are allowed to use automatic deduction of return type and it works like a charm without the trailing return type.

Comment: @Danvil answer change, it is expected after all.

Comment: I am not sure about this. The error only appears for a function with trailing return type. And this is not mentioned at that location of the standard...

Comment: One might add that the trailing return type is part of the declaration. Name lookup inside the declaration of a member function doesn't fall under the special case of [basic.lookup.unqual]/8 (although the footnote is a bit confusing)

Comment: What is [basic.lookup.unqual]/8?

Comment: @Danvil It postpones name lookup e.g. inside the body of member functions and inside NSDMI until after the class' definition has completed.

Comment: @dyp: Thank's I found it in the standard! So the take home message is that for `decltype` in a trailing return type the declaration must be before, while for many other cases it does not matter?

Comment: @Danvil Not sure. When I first learned from a similar issue, my take-home message was that *the trailing-return-type is part of the declaration*. When you already know that, another important fact is that *name lookup inside a class is only postponed inside a definition (e.g. of a member function)*.